# Laravel notification via method changes not coming in toMail method

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have one class where I calculate variables in via method and the same variable I want to use in `toMail` method but it's always null in the `toMail` Method. any idea why?

```
class FinancialQuestionnaireSubmissionNotification extends Notification implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable,SerializesModels, GlobalMailHelperTrait;

    public Lead $lead;
    public $code;

    public function __construct(Lead $lead)
    {
        $this->lead = $lead->fresh();         
                          
    }
    public function via($notifiable)
    {

        $this->code = 'xyz';            
       
        return ['mail'];
    }
    /**
     * Get the mail representation of the notification.
     */
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {                    
        dd($this->code);
    }   

    /**
     * Get the array representation of the notification.
     */
    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
}
```

here my `$this->code` is always null why even after setting that variable in via method!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using ShouldQueue interface, this is serialized before being pushed onto the queue.

so the code will be null because when job is pushed onto the queue, and at that point, the $code property is set to 'xyz'. However, when the job is actually processed and the toMail method is called, it's a separate instance of the class, and the code property reset to its initial value.

one thing you can do is,

```
public function __construct(Lead $lead)
{
    // other code
    $this->code = 'xyz';         
}

public function via($notifiable)
{
    return ['mail'];
}
```

Now, the $code property will be properly set when the job is pushed onto the queue, and it will retain its value when the toMail method is executed.